# For duplicate records, set value mysql

Tags: mysql, join, null, duplicates, fill

I have a table in mysql that looks like this:

```
BusinessName ABN Status CountOfRecordsPerBusinessName
abccompany   123 Registered 2
abccompany   null Deregistered 2
```

Where business name is duplicated, and the ABN = null for Deregistered but not null for Registered status, I want to set the null ABN to 123.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can try doing an update self join here:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.BusinessName = t2.BusinessName AND
       t1.ABN IS NULL AND
       t2.ABN IS NOT NULL
SET t1.ABN = t2.ABN;
```

The basic idea here is to join a given business record where `ABN` is `NULL` to one from the same business where `ABN` is not `NULL`.  Then, pull across the non `NULL` `ABN` value from the second to the first record.  We don't have to worry about accidentally updating non duplicates, because the join condition would always fail for those.

Comment: hmm.. i have over 2mil records, is there a faster query for this purpose?

Comment: You may find that adding indices to the `BusinessName` and `ABN` columns speeds up the update.  We could also try joining to a materialized view with indices, but before we go that route try adding an index and using the above query.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is pretty hard to do because BusinessName and ABN are many characters, so it's difficult to index.

Comment: The only optimizations I can think of involve an index.